# Maintaining initial source_node -> end_node in traversal method - Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a custom postgres traversal function that returns a set list of parent_nodes from an initial starting point. I'd like to modify the traversal function to take a list of starting points, and maintain the relationship between starting point -> destination nodes within the result set but am failing to find a way to do this.

The Table SchemaL

```
links
    child_id 
    parent_id
    link_type
```

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.reverse_link_traversal(source_id bigint, link_types text[], depth_count integer)
RETURNS TABLE(parent_id bigint)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    begin
        if 
            depth_count > 0 and EXISTS(
                select parent_id
                from links
                where child_id = source_id and link_type = ANY(link_types)
            )
        then         
            return query 
            select parent_id
            from links
            where child_id = source_id and link_type = ANY(link_types)
            union select * from reverse_link_traversal(
                (
                    select parent_id 
                    from links 
                    where child_id = source_id and link_type = ANY(link_types)
                ), 
                link_types,
            );
        else
            return query 
            select parent_id
            from links
            where child_id = source_id and link_type = ANY(link_types);
        end if;
    end if;
end $function$;
```

The goal would be to update source_id bigint to source_ids bigint[], and use this result set to traverse multiple starting nodes of the tree at once.

As an example:

Lets say I have the following data

```
child_id | parent_id | link_type
1 - 4 - x
4 - 5 - x
2 - 6 - x
6 - 7 - x
```

Current Version:

```
(child_id = 1) as source_id 
returns (parent_ids = [4, 5]

(child_id = 2) as source_id 
returns (parent_ids = [6, 7])
```

New Version would:

```
(child_id = [1, 2]) as source_id 
returns (parent_ids = [(1,4), (1,5), (2,6), (2,7)]
```

but I'm failing to see a way to maintain the initial set as you move along the tree. One idea was to include a path variable at each level, something like this:

```
ARRAY[parent_id] as path  -- initial node 
path || parent_id as path  -- add to at each point
```

but that still lacks a way to group together to produce the final result set. Does anyone know of a better way for link traversal that produces these results?

Thanks!